# Spark JDBC Dataset has the database type when loading in Java

Tags: apache-spark

When loading a Spark Dataset from JDBC, the datatype is reflecting from the database datatype, for example, if database table has type, "decimal (22,0)", it will load into Dataset as that type

```
enter code here
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read()
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("url", url)
                .option("query", "select COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 where 1=2")
                .option("user", username)
                .option("password", password)
                .option("driver", driverClass)
                .load();
enter code here
```

When trying to append new row to that Dataset in Java, it will crash with invalid data type as there is no exacting mataching of that type in Java

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are appending wrong row, you can use this type. Please add rest of your code.

```
scala> val df =Seq("1111111111111111111111").toDF("val").select('val.cast("decimal(22,0)"))
res42: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [val: decimal(22,0)]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- val: decimal(22,0) (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I am using java but here it is

Comment: I am using java but here it is
    






















Sorry I could not paste my entire code here in the comment as it said it was too long
I am using Java and creating a Row from an Object array
Elements that I put in are 
int, Timestamp, Double, Double, Timestamp

  Object[] result = (Object[])rowData.toArray(new Object[0]);
            rows.add(RowFactory.create(result));

It fails at the Double data type

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (11.0) of the type (java.lang.Double) cannot be converted to decimal(22,0)

Comment: I would create new dataframe from your Rows an then using spark sql cast that double typed column to decimal(22,0) then union to your main dataset, just check printSchema if both datasets are identical

Comment: Thanks chlebek
Actually, the issue went away if I set the value using BigDecimal instead of Double
Second question, how do I flush the data into the database table? The following call seems to invoked but it does nothing to the database
  Dataset<Row> newDataset = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, structure);
        newDataset.write() .format("jdbc")
                .option("url", url)
                .option("dbtable", table)
                .option("user", username)
                .option("password", password)
                .option("driver", driverClass);

Comment: I tried write mode append but still cannot see the data saved to the database

  newDataset.write()
                .mode("append")
                .option("url", url)
                .option("user", username)
                .option("dbtable",table)
                .option("password", password)
                .option("driver", driverClass)
              ;

Comment: I added the .save() but now it is complaining about drop table permission. Should I not be able to use Override save mode?
        newDataset.write()
        .format("jdbc")
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .option("url", url)
                .option("user", username)
                .option("dbtable",table)
                .option("password", password)
                .option("driver", driverClass)
                .save();
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot drop the table 'test1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: your code looks correct, maybe something is wrong with your db, I was woring with postgres and mysql and I didn't have this error.

Comment: Hi chlebek
It looks like it is a bug in the apache spark java library. I can use Append mode so it will not attempt to drop and re-create the database table. I am now executing another query first to delete all records outside Spark. Everything is working now. Thank you for all your help!